# How to specify to not use .NET 4.7.2 in app.config

Tags: .net-framework

After installing the Visual Studio 2019 preview, and the required .NET framework 4.7.2, I found that another (.NET) application does not start anymore, and gives me an error:

> The value specified in System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension caused an exception

This application is not mine, so I can't change the source code.

Is there a way to specify in the application's config file to not use 4.7.2, but 4.5 instead? I changed the sku version in the [supportedRuntime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/startup/supportedruntime-element) section from 4.5 to 4.5.1 and 4.5.3 (which are both installed), but that didn't change anything.

```xml
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.3" />
```

---

My OS is Windows 10 Enterprise, release 1709.

Here's a screenshot showing the .NET installs I have:

[image: .NET Framework installations]

And

[image: Microsoft optional components]

Comment: I think the required .NET framework version is defined during compilation or in the source code. So I don't think you can change that for the executable only.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke If that were the case it wouldn't have been 4.7.2 in the first place.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, I added a screenshot, and Yes, I probably meant _targeting packs_ ;-). I also found out that my problem might be caused by having both 4.7.1 and 4.7.2 installed: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/307924/net-472-issue-with-rehosted-workflow-designer.html. I'm currently trying to find out what's the best way to uninstall 4.7.1

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 10 Enterprise, release 1709

Comment: @Ramhound Correct, that's exactly what I did. I now have 4.7.2, and I think I want to revert to 4.7.1. Uninstalling VS2019 didn't help here, and neither did running the 4.7.1 offline installer with the /repair or /uninstall option

Comment: 4.7.1 isn’t applicable to your Windows installation.  Anyways, [the .net cleanup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/08/28/net-framework-cleanup-tool-users-guide/) should remove 4.7.2 but I don’t believe this exception is related to you installing 4.7.2

Comment: @Ramhound Believe it or not, but uninstalling [KB4073120](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4073120/microsoft-net-framework-4-7-2-for-windows-10-version-1709-and-windows), which is the .NET Framework 4.7.2 for Windows 10:1709 just fixed it.

Comment: If reverting to 4.7.1 solved your issue you should submit an answer.  I forgot that, the .NET Framework, also went to cumulative updates recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no answer to my question, simply because it is not possible to have more than one 4.x version installed at the same time. Any .NET application that targets 4.x will run using the latest installed version.

Reverting to 4.7.1 is not intuitive, because the 4.7 versions do not appear in the Add/Remove programs section of Windows. What I did was:

1. Uninstall VS 2019
2. Start *appwiz.cpl*
3. Select *Display installed updates*
4. Uninstall [KB4073120](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4073120/microsoft-net-framework-4-7-2-for-windows-10-version-1709-and-windows), which is the .NET Framework 4.7.2 for Windows 10:1709
5. Reboot